# Using date in ref cusor with pl/sql

Tags: date, plsql, oracle11g

I have a var: *acc_date*  with type date.

It takes its value from a cursor and when I insert its value to logger table as:

```
insert into logger values(1,acc_date);
```

the out put when a select it from logger is

```
1   01-JAN-10
```

but when i use it to compare with another Date value in another cursor as

```
OPEN c_get_date_id 
 for 'SELECT Date_D.DATEKEY from Date_D where Date_D.DATEVALUE='||acc_date;
     EXIT WHEN c_get_date_id%NOTFOUND;
     FETCH c_get_date_id
        INTO date_id;
      insert into logger values (1,'Now with date_id'||date_id);
CLOSE c_get_date_id;
```

an error occurs:

```
Error report:
ORA-00904: "JAN": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "HW.FILLFACT", line 82
ORA-06512: at line 1
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least add some quotes around the date:

```
....'  where Date_D.DATEVALUE='''||acc_date||'''';
```

Double apostrophes within a string will be concatenated to a single apostrophe, so that the expression becomes

```
 where Date_D.DATEVALUE='....';
```

In order to make the thing more foolprof, I'd also add a specific `to_date`:

```
.... ' where Date_D.DATEVALUE=to_date(''' || acc_date || ', ''dd-mon-yy'')';
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your dynamic query is being interpreted as:

```
SELECT Date_D.DATEKEY from Date_D where Date_D.DATEVALUE=01-JAN-10
```

The error is because string representation of the date isn't being quoted, so it's seeing `JAN` as an identifier - and nothing matches that name. You could enclose the date value in quotes:

```
open c_get_date_id
  for 'SELECT Date_D.DATEKEY from Date_D where Date_D.DATEVALUE='''||acc_date||'''';
```

But you're treating the date as a string, and forcing conversion of all your table values to strings to be compared, using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT. It would be better to compare it as a date (although this somewhat assumes all your values have the time portion set to midnight):

```
open c_get_date_id 
  for select date_d.datekey from date_d where date_d.datevalue = acc_date;
```

Your exit is in the wrong place though, and you aren't looping, so maybe you want:

```
open c_get_date_id 
  for select date_d.datekey from date_d where date_d.datevalue = acc_date;
loop
  fetch c_get_date_id into date_id;
  exit when c_get_date_id%notfound;
  insert into logger values (1, 'Now with date_id'||date_id);
end loop;
close c_get_date_id;
```

If you only have one value in the first place though, you probably don't want a loop or cursor at all, and could do a simple `select ... into` instead:

```
select date_d.datekey into date_id from date_d
where date_d.datevalue = acc_date;
insert into logger values (1, 'Now with date_id'||date_id);
```

Though of course that would error if you had no matching date in your table, or more than one, and you'd need to deal with that - but then I guess you'd want to anyway.